# Finding in site by text

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm in way to make a bot for faster shopping. 
Right now I have a litte problem. I don't know how to find element in website by text. I'm intrested in that size table. I want to choose for example 41 1/3. Whole button is clickable. You can't click on text.
That's how it looks: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAvZv.png

That's how code of 1 button looks:

```
<div class="articleSize___select___1n9yK"> == $0
<span class="articleSize___select-number___3Zijv articleSize___select-number--no-footnote___D3jwF">41 1/3</span> == $0
</div>
```

What my code look like:

```
 browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '41 1/3')]").click()
```

I want to change 41 1/3 to variable. How to change it?

Comment: Oh I did it finally:
`browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '"+rozmiar+"')]").click()`

Comment: make sure to add the html tag `//span` in the xpath rather `//*`, which may break if there is another element added to the page with `41 1/3` text before this span element in the dom.